# Hagbah in a partitioned room

Tags: halacha, torah-service, see-sight-vision-blind, architecture-design, hagbah-gelilah

Over Yom Tov I was in a shul which was converted from a house into a shul.  The sanctuary was divided by a walled staircase, such that one could not see from one part into the other, like so:

```
 |    | |    |
 |    | |    |
 |           |
 |___________|
```

So if hagbah was performed in the middle, because of the angle it would not be seen all the way back on either side.  Does the person doing hagbah here have to carry the Sefer Torah mid-hagbah from one side to the other so that everyone can see?

Comment: This sort of question can be asked about many women's sections

Comment: acc to the Ramban ,yes